# Paypal Donate Button in Phonegap Build Application

Tags: cordova, button, plugins, paypal

i have two questions towards the integration of a Paypal-Donation-Button in my Phonegap Application. The application is being compiled via the build.phonegap online service. First of all i tried to implement Paypal via the inappbrowser plugin but it fails, because it works only with a href="" link relations and paypal requires a POST method.

I tried  form but it did not work. An error always accures: application error a network error occurred (link of paypal payment).

Then i saw that a phonegap cordova paypal plugin is avialable. I read the documentation and did not discover any donation buttons - only pay buttons.

So is it reasonable to integrate it? And does it even work with the online cloud service of build.phonegap?

Best Regards

Dimitri P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try to confirm one thing firstly.
Does the plugin work? regarding donate or pay. Wouldn't it be the same? (People send money to you). the only difference is word "pay" or "donate". IF the plugin render nicely, then we can just change the value(text) of button from original "Buy NOw!" to "Donate"

```
  <button id="buyNowBtn"> Buy Now !</button> // button with word "buyNow"
  <button id="buyNowBtn"> Donate</button> // button with word "Donate"
```

I haven't try the plugin[(Read here)](https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-cordova-plugin-released/) , but it come from paypal itself. So it is most likely working plugin. 
I cannot test it now, because I am not sure when will people donate to me :)

Comment: Nice idea. Sometimes are the simplest solutions the best. i will try it out and report

Comment: Ok it didnt work unfortunately. I was not able to connect the buttons i pasted with the rest of the plugin. Seems that the documentation is pretty poor.

Comment: But i found a workaround for the phonegap build cloud service. Just make the donate button online and to avoid a POST form and to get an a href link choose after the button creation the email version. It contains a link. Afterwards you can combine it with the webinapp plugin and it works!

Comment: hi, i am little confused. did my answer work? would like to know, who knows if i will start using phonegap again anytime soon